# Does genType library supports generating types from typescript to rescript/reasonml?

Tags: reactjs, reason, reason-react, rescript

I’m very new to reasonml/rescript community, What I know genType generates TS/flow types from rescript component while working in existing Typescript/flow codebase. Is there any other way around like I’m working on existing rescript codebase, does it generates bindings for rescript from typescript component/library types?

Comment: Answered in https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/gentype-typescript-to-rescript-types/3261

Comment: Thanks @Yawar for linking community answer